# Azure function inside Sharepoint site redirects to login window

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, api, azure-functions

I put on a Sharepoint site an ajax request to my azure function.

This azure function requires authentication because its logic
depends on which user is using my sharepoint site. All users
who test my sharepoint site have authenticated this azure function
by calling it in a separated browser tab.

The problem is that when this azure function is called inside the
Sharepoint site - a request to login.windows.net appears.
I can see this in my browser network tools.

Why this is happening? A user who was logged into the Sharepoint
had already authenticated this azure function. Moreover,
he could call this azure function in a separated browser tab.

Does it mean that Sharepoint calls azure functions not on behalf of
the currently logged user but as a some kind of special user?

If yes - how can I authenticate this special user to my azure function?

Thank you,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the ajax request with Azure Function was redirected to
login window was the lack of the following lines in the ajax request:

xhrFields: {
withCredentials: true
},

I have found a great help here:
https://briantjackett.com/2018/05/01/calling-azure-ad-secured-azure-function-externally-from-javascript/